# c++ Char input takes the first letter but char casting doesnt

Tags: c++

I dont understand the datatype char very well. Its because of that example:

```
char test;
cin >> test;
cout << test;
```

If i input now more than one char, the program only prints the first letter.

```
char test = (char)"Hello";
```

But If I cast a string like hello to a char, the program doesnt take the first letter.

```
void menu() {
    char mode = ' ';
    cout << "Gebe einen Modus an. 1 Addition, 2 Subtraktion, 3 Multiplikation, 4 Division: ";
    cin >> mode;
    switch (mode) {
    case '1':
        addition();
        break;
    case '2':
        subtraktion();
        break;
    case '3':
        multiplikation();
        break;
    case '4':
        division();
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Ungueltige Eingabe, versuch es nochmal\n";
        menu();
        break;

    }
}
```

Also in this example, If I give the program as an input more than one letter, the default condition will be executed so many times, as the length of the input.

I dont understand those three examples well, could anybody explain me everything in easy from the start=? That would be really nice! Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0):

`char` is for only one character. If you want to take multiple characters, you have to use array of `char` or string.

`char test = (char)"Hello";`
Please use this:
`char test[6] = "Hello"`;

Comment: `(char)"Hello"` says  - take the **address** of the string literal, interpret it as an integer, and then truncate that integer so only one least-significant byte remains. `(char)"Hello"` does not produce character `H`, except perhaps by pure coincidence.

Comment: Yes, you are right. @IgorTandetnik. I was focusing on the questioner's string printing. I didn't notice about I might gave a wrong logic.
But `(char)"Hello"` will produce an error. I have edited that line.

Answer (score 0):

1. since you expect a type of char (which is one character, so one letter only) from stdin you will only get the first character you input.
2. you can not cast a string literal "Hello" (which is a pointer-type: const char*) to char like that. You would have to do the following to only get the first character:

```
char test = *("Hello");
```

Learn more about pointers and references here: https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: Ok, im understanding now the first two problems, but what about the third? stdin expects a type of char, so only one letter, but if I type more than one letter, it prints "ungueltige Eingabe..." multiple times. How does that work, if it only takes the first character=

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding what a [char](https://openstack.by/biblioteka/w3/www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_data_types_char.asp.html) is and mistaken it for a [string](https://openstack.by/biblioteka/w3/www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_data_types_string.asp.html) which is an array of char with a [terminating null character](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-a-null-terminated-string-in-c-cplusplus).

> The char data type is used to store a **single** character.

Therefore, you will only get 1 character from the input. In order to get a stream of multiple characters you should use the datatype char* or std::string.